# Regular expression that accepts integer numbers and null

Tags: regex

Can someone help me in writing regular expression that accepts integer values and null(word null or NULL) but not decimals and strings.

I tried with expressions:

```
/^([nN][uU][lL][lL])?|(-?\d+?)?$/     
/^(null|NULL)?|(-?\d+?)?$/
```

but they are accepting strings and combination of number and strings.

Comment: Because your anchors are not in factor with the two branches of the alternation. The first has the beginning anchors, the second has the end anchor.

Comment: Just use a group around the pattern between the anchors: `^(null|NULL|-?\d+)?$` (this will also allow an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you want:-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)((null)*\\d*)*");
String s = "null123null";
System.out.println(s.matches(p.toString()));
```

output

true